# How to access the variables assigned in a drl file in class which invoked the drl

Tags: drools

```
package rules

import beans.LoginBean;
import beans.MessageBean;

rule "Hello World"
    when
        $a : LoginBean();
        $b: MessageBean();
        eval($a.getUserName().equals("admin"))
    then
       $b.setMessage("Admin logged in");
end
```

How do i access the value set here by a class which called the rule class

Comment: You question doesn't make sense. A "class" does not "invoke a DRL". There is no such thing as a "rule class".

Comment: What i meant by rule class was a class where i declare knowledbase,session and write  kSession.fireAllRules();

Answer (score 0):

This rule should be better written as

```
rule "Hello World"
when
    $a : LoginBean( userName == "admin" );
    $b: MessageBean();
then
   $b.setMessage( $a.getUserName() + " logged in");
end
```

The bound variables `$a` and `$b` are set due to the presence of facts (= Java objects) in working memory. There is the Java API for the session object which can be used to insert such facts, or the facts can be created and inserted by other rules.

Comment: Ok help me in accessing the message i set here in drl file in a class where i wrote kSession.fireAllRules();